# Uploading an XAMPP subfolder to a web server

Tags: html, .htaccess, xampp, relative-path

I'm completely new to XAMPP, and don't know much more than HTML and CSS. I've put my website into a subfolder in `htdocs` called `test`. In my HTML, I have relative links that look like `/test/path/to/image.jpg`.

I was planning on uploading the subfolder `test` to a server using FTP. My question is, will I encounter any problems because of the way I have my links formatted? When my website is live, I'd like for the URL to look more like `example.com/path/to/image.jpg` rather than `example.com/test/path/to/image.jpg`. Is it better to use `../` to define my paths instead?

I've seen some similar questions that required people to use the `.htaccess` file, but I can't find that/don't know how to use it. Again, sorry for my total lack of knowledge on this; I'd be super grateful for any help.

Comment: use `<base href="<your domain/subfolder>" />` in head tag, keep everything like original html. should work.

Comment: Thanks! But what about uploading to a web host server and everything? Would I use the `htdocs` folder or the `test` folder? I have a `favicon.ico` in the `htdocs` folder, but I'm assuming that I can easily move it to my `test` folder where my index file is and still have it show up.

Answer (score 0):

> /test/path/to/image.jpg

Isn't a relative path/link - it is absolute, meaning the web server would try to serve the file from **http://www.example.com/test/path/to/image.jpg**.  If you would like that file to be served using a relative URL, you should use:

> path/to/image.jpg

Which will serve the file **relative** to the page that is requesting it.  If the requesting page is in the test directory, and document root is the test directory, the server would deliver **http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg**.